# How to add 'Delete Post' functionality on list items with React & Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm currently taking the Modern React with Redux course from Udemy.

On **posts_show** component I can get the id from react-router's params object from the uri as shown below.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPost, deletePost } from "../actions/index";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class PostsShow extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        // if (!this.props.post) { if we don't have it go and grab that thing}

        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.fetchPost(id);
    }

    onDeleteClick() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;

        this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { post } = this.props;

        if(!post) {             // BEFORE THE DATA IS LOADED, WE SHOULD RETURN (RENDER) ANOTHER THING.
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">Back to Index</Link>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right"
                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}
                >
                    Delete Post
                </button>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <h6>Categories: {post.categories}</h6>
                <p>{post.content}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) { // (application state, ownProps)
    return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost })(PostsShow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the action creator:

```js
export function deletePost(id, callback) {
    const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`)
        .then(() => callback());

    return {
        type: DELETE_POST,
        payload: id
    }
}
```

and here is the reducer:

```js
export default function(state = {}, action) { 
    switch (action.type) {

        case DELETE_POST:
            return _.omit(state, action.payload);
```

Now I would like to add the same functionality for the **posts_index component**.
I'd like to add Delete Post buttons for each individual list item. I assume that it's ok to use the same action_creator and reducer for the task, however I can't reach the id property of the individual list item and pass it to the onDeleteClick function on the posts_index component.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPosts, deletePost} from "../actions/index";
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class PostsIndex extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    onDeleteClick() {
        console.log(this.props.posts);
        alert('clicked');
    }

    renderPosts() {
        return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
            return <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
                <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
                    {post.title}

                </Link>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right"
                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}
                >Delete {post.id}
                </button>
            </li>
        })
    }

    render() {
        // console.log(this.props.posts);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-xs-right">
                    <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts/new">
                        Add a Post
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <h3>Posts</h3>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.renderPosts()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { posts: state.posts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, deletePost })(PostsIndex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onClick to

```
onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(post.id)}
```

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: somehow I need to pass this post.id to the method: `onDeleteClick() {

        this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, thank you for your help!

```js
onDeleteClick(id) {
        this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }

    renderPosts() {
        return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
            return <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
                <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
                    {post.title}

                </Link>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right"
                    onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(post.id)}
                >Delete {post.id}
                </button>
            </li>
        })
    }
```